# Problem in adjusting the mark size in pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to adjust the marker size in the following `tikspicture`. Unfortunately, when I configure the plot by adding `mark size=0.85`, the compiler complains with the following message.

```
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) ...ark=*, mark size=0.85, draw=black, smooth]
```

Adding `pt` unit to `mark size=0.85` does not help. Also, specifying the marker color does not have any effect although I forced the color to be black (it will print out in blue). The following is a MWE when I take out the `mark size` option from the code.

```
\documentclass[crop=true,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth
\setlength\figureheight{4cm}
\setlength\figurewidth{4cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} %[scale=1.0]
    \begin{polaraxis}[%
        axis on top,
        width = \figurewidth,
        height = \figureheight,
        scale only axis,
        ymin=5.e5, ymax=1.5e6,
        xtick      ={0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330},
        xticklabels={0, $\frac{\pi}6$, $\frac{\pi}3$, $\frac{\pi}2$, $\frac{2\pi}3$, $\frac{5\pi}6$, $\pi$ , $\frac{7\pi}6$, $\frac{4\pi}3$, $\frac{3\pi}2$, $\frac{5\pi}3$, $\frac{11\pi}6$},
        ytick = {5e5, 1.e6, 1.5e6},
    ]
    \addplot table [%
        col sep=comma, trim cells=true, %
        x=x, y=y, %
        data cs=polarrad, mark=*, draw=black, smooth]
        {mydata.dat};
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture} %[scale=1.0]
    \begin{axis}[%
        axis on top,
        width = \figurewidth,
        height = \figureheight,
        scale only axis,
        xmin=0, xmax=6.2832,
        ymin=5.e5, ymax=1.5e6,
        xlabel = {$\theta$},
        ylabel = {$\Gamma_{\theta}$},
        grid=major,
        xtick      ={0, 0.7854, 1.5708, 2.3562, 3.1416, 3.9270, 4.7124, 5.4978, 6.2832},
        xticklabels={0, $\frac{\pi}4$, $\frac{\pi}2$, $\frac{3\pi}4$, $\pi$ , $\frac{5\pi}4$, $\frac{3\pi}2$, $\frac{7\pi}4$, $2\pi$},
        ]
        \addplot table [%
            col sep=comma, trim cells=true, %
            x=x, y=y, %
            mark=*, draw=black, smooth]%
            {mydata.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The content of `mydata.dat` is as follows.

```
# mydata
x,y
0.0000,1.1686E+06
0.0175,1.1686E+06
0.0349,1.1446E+06
0.0524,1.1165E+06
0.0698,1.1034E+06
0.0873,1.1038E+06
0.1047,1.1059E+06
0.1222,1.1317E+06
0.1396,1.1500E+06
0.1571,1.1372E+06
0.1745,1.1173E+06
0.1920,1.1218E+06
0.2094,1.1257E+06
0.2269,1.1203E+06
0.2443,1.1078E+06
0.2618,1.1043E+06
0.2793,1.1239E+06
0.2967,1.1228E+06
0.3142,1.0912E+06
0.3316,1.0909E+06
```

Could someone help me adjust the size and color of the marker?

Comment: You have to give the options to `\addplot` not to the `table`. Change the mark options' location and it should work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mark options and plot related options should be supplied to the `\addplot` command to have effect on the current plot

```
\documentclass[crop=true,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}


\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth
\setlength\figureheight{4cm}
\setlength\figurewidth{4cm}


\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma, trim cells=true]{
%# mydata
x,y
0.0000,1.1686E+06
0.0175,1.1686E+06
0.0349,1.1446E+06
0.0524,1.1165E+06
0.0698,1.1034E+06
0.0873,1.1038E+06
0.1047,1.1059E+06
0.1222,1.1317E+06
0.1396,1.1500E+06
0.1571,1.1372E+06
0.1745,1.1173E+06
0.1920,1.1218E+06
0.2094,1.1257E+06
0.2269,1.1203E+06
0.2443,1.1078E+06
0.2618,1.1043E+06
0.2793,1.1239E+06
0.2967,1.1228E+06
0.3142,1.0912E+06
0.3316,1.0909E+06
}\mydata

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} %[scale=1.0]
    \begin{polaraxis}[%
        axis on top,
        width = \figurewidth,
        height = \figureheight,
        scale only axis,
        ymin=5.e5, ymax=1.5e6,
        xtick      ={0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330},
        xticklabels={0, $\frac{\pi}6$, $\frac{\pi}3$, $\frac{\pi}2$, $\frac{2\pi}3$, $\frac{5\pi}6$, 
                    $\pi$ , $\frac{7\pi}6$, $\frac{4\pi}3$, $\frac{3\pi}2$, $\frac{5\pi}3$, $\frac{11\pi}6$},
        ytick = {5e5, 1.e6, 1.5e6},
    ]
    \addplot[mark=*, mark size=0.2,draw=black, smooth] table [x=x, y=y,data cs=polarrad]{\mydata};
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture} %[scale=1.0]
    \begin{axis}[%
        axis on top,
        width = \figurewidth,
        height = \figureheight,
        scale only axis,
        xmin=0, xmax=6.2832,
        ymin=5.e5, ymax=1.5e6,
        xlabel = {$\theta$},
        ylabel = {$\Gamma_{\theta}$},
        grid=major,
        xtick      ={0, 0.7854, 1.5708, 2.3562, 3.1416, 3.9270, 4.7124, 5.4978, 6.2832},
        xticklabels={0, $\frac{\pi}4$, $\frac{\pi}2$, $\frac{3\pi}4$, 
                     $\pi$ , $\frac{5\pi}4$, $\frac{3\pi}2$, $\frac{7\pi}4$, $2\pi$},
        ]
        \addplot [mark=*, mark size=0.2,draw=black, smooth] table [x=x, y=y] {\mydata};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]